# Changing the \autoref name for Chapter

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to change the name the function `\autoref` (from the hyperref package) uses for chapters. By default it outputs "chapter X" (lower case c) but I want it to output "Chapter X" (upper case c). In my document I can successfully redefine the `\chapterautorefname` function to something else without generating warnings or errors, but the value I assign to it seems to be ignored. I've also tried normally defining it (which nicely gives an already defined error) and redefining `\Chapterautorefname` (which generated a nice, not yet defined error).

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{hyperref}               

\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Something}

% Document
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
In \autoref{chap:two}...

\chapter{Two}
\label{chap:two}

\end{document}
```

Generated output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Package `babel` supports many languages, therefore you have to put the redefinition into `\extrasenglish`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
In \autoref{chap:two}...

\chapter{Two}
\label{chap:two}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

It is also explained in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) of `hyperref`.

Comment: I went through the manual again but babel isn't even mentioned in support for other packages so I'm not sure where you got your info. But anyway, this works :).

Comment: @RoyT.: The example in the manual is: `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}\addto\extrasngerman{\def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}}`. It can be found at the place, where `\autoref` is explained.