# How to replace 'subsubsection' with just 'section' whilst using autoref package?

Tags: sectioning, labels, autoref

I am using the `autoref` package to make labelling of sections, figures and graphs much easier, and it really is much easier. However, when I am referring to a particular subsubsection, I just want it to appear in the final document as `section 3.1.1` yet it appears to render as `subsubsection 3.1.1`.

How do I disable the usage of `subsubsection X.Y.Z` and just have it say `section` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between \ref and \autoref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137432/whats-the-difference-between-ref-and-autoref)

Comment: Also see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186946/) or the [`cleveref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package.

Comment: It probably depends on whether you are using `babel`. Look for `\autorefname` in the `hyperref` manual and the example about `\subsectionautorefname` (page 20 in my version of the manual, from January 2020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer did not help, I instead receieved several errors saying that the `\subsubsectionname` had not been defined. I instead solved it by using the following :

`\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}`

This renamed all `subsubsection` usage in the document.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual (page 18 in my 2019 version) use

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionname}{section}
```

Comment: No, this didn't work. I'm getting all sorts of errors about how the command is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just add that this capitalizes **S**ection x.x.x but maybe that was intended.

Another workaround is:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\let\subsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
\let\subsubsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
```

This way you only need to specify the name once as sub and subsub follow suite.