# How to force all subsubsections to be referenced as sections?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I am using the `hyperref` and `autoref` package to do cross-referencing in my document. When I am referring to `subsubsection` such as 3.1.1, I want to it to compile as `section 3.1.1` and not `subsubsection 3.1.1`. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace 'subsubsection' with just 'section' whilst using autoref package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540533/how-to-replace-subsubsection-with-just-section-whilst-using-autoref-package)

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual (`texdoc hyperref`) page 18 in my 2019 version:

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionname}{section}
```